# Where did these dbo._trace_ Stored Procedures come from?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm looking at some databases at a new company and one in particular has a bunch of Stored Procedures named dbo.`_trace`_*

SQL Default Trace is ON, but I'm not sure if these are related, and if they were, I don't know why I would see them in one database on the server but not in other databases on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stored procedure contents.
It they begin like the following example, they could be server side traces someone has created.

```
Create a Queue declare @rc int declare @TraceID int declare @maxfilesize bigint set @maxfilesize = 100 Create the trace exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N’E:\demo\demotrace’, @maxfilesize, NULL if (@rc != 0) goto error --Set the events declare @on bit set @on = 1 exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 31, @on exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 8, @on
```